# Not able to login as Jenkins admin and cannot able to see options and build jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I  cannot able t login jenkins as admin, While i try to do so.It's showing as "No Valid crumb was included in the request"and cannot able to see the manage jenkins or any other options.
Also i have no access to build the jobs either.So can anyone please help me to resolve this or let me know how can i reset this.

Note; jenkins is loading but without any users logged in.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to clear cookies.

Comment: I reset cookies and edited the config.xml user security"from TRUE to FALSE. Then it was fine.Can you please post it as answer  @zett42